# offline recyclerview in android like whatsapp, Facebook, Gmail app?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, offline

I develop android application json parsing using Volley library into Recyclerview. I need to open app in offline mode. whatever data loaded in online that data show in offline mode. How i will get?

Comment: you have to save data in data base when you are in online and retrieve that and show that when you are offline

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like offline RecyclerView.

They all storing large data into the database. This database is using for many purpose.

1. Fast Loading
2. Lazy Loading
3. Offline Loading

When application appear to be **OFFLINE** then instead of calling API app displays data from the storage. Storage can be anything like **Shared Preferences** and **SQLite Database**

Answer (score 0):

You should make a database and sync your data with it when Online.
If mobile goes offline, the app should use database as it's data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by utilising Volley built in response cache. By default response cache is enabled, unless it is set in headers of response received from Server: **Cache-Control: no cache**

This can be done in either of following manners:

1. Use:

`request.getCacheEntry().data`

when request has been formed and can be a last check before you add it to the queue and the call is made.

2. Use:

`queue.getCache().get(url).data`

as it retrieves the cache through the RequestQueue by passing the request key, which by default is the request’s url

Hope this helps